# Match a specific number of digits not preceded or followed by digits

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a string:

```
string = u'11a2ee22b333c44d5e66e777e8888'
```

I want to find all `k` consecutive chunks of digits where `n <= k <= m`.

Using regular expression only:
say for example `n=2` and `m=3` 
   using `(?:\D|^)(\d{2,3})(?:\D|$)`

```
re.findall(u'(?:\D|^)(\d{2,3})(?:\D|$)',u'11a2ee22b333c44d5e66e777e8888')
```

Gives this output:

```
['11', '333', '66']
```

Desired output:

```
['11', '22', '333', '44', '66', '777']
```

I know there are alternate solutions like:

```
filter(lambda x: re.match('^\d{2,3}$', x), re.split(u'\D',r'11a2ee22b333c44d5e66e777e8888'))
```

which gives the desired output, but I want to know what's wrong with the first approach?

It seems `re.findall` goes in sequence and skips the previous part when matched, so what can be done?

Comment: Try your pattern at https://regex101.com/ , or another of the many online Python flavored regex testers.  Some give explanations of and/or graphics showing how the pattern works.

Comment: Your non-capturing *groups* consume text.  ```re.findall``` only returns non-overlapping matches.  When you consume the text you end up creating overlaps.  Try *look ahead assertions*, *negative lookahead assertions*, positive and negative *lookbehind assertions*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** The result you show in your question is not what I'm getting:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(u'(?:\D|^)(\d{2,3})(?:\D|$)',u'11a2ee22b333c44d5e66e777e8888')
[u'11', u'22', u'44', u'66']
```

It's still missing some of the matches you want, but not the same ones.

The problem is that even though non-capturing groups like `(?:\D|^)` and `(?:\D|$)` don't *capture* what they match, they still *consume* it.

This means that the match which yields `'22'` has actually consumed:

1. `e`, with `(?:\D|^)` – not captured (but still consumed)
2. `22` with `(\d{2,3})` – captured
3. `b` with `(?:\D|$)` – not captured (but still consumed)

… so that `b` is no longer available to be matched before `333`.

You can get the result you want with lookbehind and lookahead syntax:

```
>>> re.findall(u'(?<!\d)\d{2,3}(?!\d)',u'11a2ee22b333c44d5e66e777e8888')
[u'11', u'22', u'333', u'44', u'66', u'777']
```

Here, `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind, checking that the match is not preceded by a digit, and `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead, checking that the match is not followed by a digit. Crucially, these constructions do not consume any of the string.

The various lookahead and lookbehind constructions are described in the 
[Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) section of Python's `re` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

lookaround regex,\d{2,3} means 2 or 3 digits, (?=[a-z]) means letter after digits.

```
In [136]: re.findall(r'(\d{2,3})(?=[a-z])',string)
Out[136]: ['11', '22', '333', '44', '66', '777']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could even generalize it with a function:

```
import re

string = "11a2ee22b333c44d5e66e777e8888"

def numbers(n,m):
    rx = re.compile(r'(?<!\d)(\d{' + '{},{}'.format(n,m) + '})(?!\d)')
    return rx.findall(string)

print(numbers(2,3))
# ['11', '22', '333', '44', '66', '777']
```